# What html Version to use?

Tags: html, version

I'm starting a little web application project. It is intended for tech savvy users, so I'll happily  require more or less the latest Browser versions.

So what version of HTML should I use, i.e. what should go in the document header?

Comment: Which versions are you considering?... Just use HTML5, there's no reason not to.

Comment: @Madmartigan so I guess I'm loosing nothing by HTML5 not yet fully supported by browsers? Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @theCloseRequest Why do you think it doesn't fit the Q&A format? Are some relevant facts missing?

Comment: I voted to close because it's not clear what your specific concerns are. Are you asking about a particular feature or if a certain browser supports it? That's easily found by a Google search or at http://caniuse.com/ You can use XHTML, HTML4, or HTML5 - to me it's a no-brainer, and this is going to attract answers of an opinionated nature, all pointing to HTML5.

Comment: The problem for me is I have no idea about the pros and cons of the various options (I couldn't even easily list them)

Comment: Just curious: What is one other option you are considering? HTML4?

Comment: HTML4 / XHTML ... It's been a long time since I did web projects and I vaguely remember a talk in which a strict recommendation for or against some version was made. But I guess what ever the argument was it was only valid if one had to consider older browsers.

Comment: The HTML5 doctype will "work" in any browser, it's only specific features you need to worry about.

Comment: Yes. If you want to play it safe (i.e. cater to as many browsers as possible), use only the elements that are mentioned here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html But that doesn't mean you can't simply use the HTML5 doctype declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely go the HTML5 route. If we as developers keep worrying about browsers catching up, we will never move forward.  While true, HTML5 is not fully supported by older browsers, there are tons of tools that will bring these browsers up-to-speed:

- html5shiv
  http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/
- HTML5 Enabling Script
  http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/
- HTML5 Reset
  http://html5reset.org/
- Reset CSS
  http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Lastly, [Dear Clients, The Web Has Changed. It’s Time To Use CSS3 and HTML5 Now.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/28/introducing-html5-and-css3-to-your-clients/)

Answer (score 2):

[**HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)

**HTML 5** is the newest specification for HTML, and many browsers are supporting it. `One nice thing about HTML 5 is that it attempts to stay backwards compatible`. So if you don't want to learn it just yet, you don't need to.

**For more details, demos, examples and documentation, go through:**

[HTML5 - The Newest Version of HTML](http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5/qt/what_is_html5.htm)

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp

[HTML 5 Demos and Examples](http://html5demos.com/)

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/28/introducing-html5-and-css3-to-your-clients/

[Compatibility tables for support of HTML5](http://caniuse.com/#cats=HTML5)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` suits your needs. Latest Browser understand this. Other Browser ignore this and choose better version.

Answer (score 1):

latest version of HTML is 5 , works with latest version of browsers , But, sometimes the users using older versions of browsers, So you will lose these visitors .
I advise you to use XHTML in order not to lose some visitors

**Use DOCTYPE for (HTML5) :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**Use DOCTYPE for (XHTML) :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```